# pdfkit: Imagegrid not possible - fix?

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I've tried to create a very simple .HTML file with a 2x2 image grid which looks like this:

[image: .HTML output]

I am trying to convert this .HTML file to .PDF using the `pdfkit` `(wkthmltpdf)` library. I've tried multiple CSS solutions to but they all fail to produce an identical .PDF file. An example of the .PDF file is this:

PDF output

[image: .PDF output]

The underlying code is very simple:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_style.css"/>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="IL_fig1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="IL_fig2.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="IL_fig3.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="IL_fig4.png" />
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .image {
  width: 40%;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Python code:

```
options = {
    'enable-local-file-access': None,
    'dpi': 300,
    'print_media_type': True}
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_file(path_html,path_pdf, configuration=config,options=options)
```

Comment: So where is your python code?

Comment: Please see the updated version.